# Instantiate defined object with Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I know that you can instantiate anonymous types with Linq but I am looking to instantiate an object I have already defined. Every time I do, all the properties are returned with their defaults (null, 0, etc.) Is there a way to make this work?

I've tried something like this:

```
ServiceDepartment[] serviceDepartments = (from d in departments
                                          orderby d.department_name
                                          select new ServiceDepartment
                                          {
                                              DepartmentID = d.department_id,
                                              DepartmentName = d.department_name
                                          }).ToArray();
```

Comment: that should work, do you have the sample data you ran it on? Otherwise it seems that your source data in fact has those default values.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it and it worked with Linq to Sql just not working with subsonic I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work absolutely fine. Do your properties definitely work? I suggest you put breakpoints on them and see whether they get called, and what the values are at that point.

EDIT: Okay, this sounds like it could be a Subsonic issue. I suggest you force the last part to be done in-process using `AsEnumerable`:

```
var query  = from d in departments
             orderby d.department_name 
             select new { id = d.department_id, name = d.department_name };

var serviceDepartments = query.AsEnuemrable()
                              .Select(x => new ServiceDepartment
                                      {
                                          DepartmentName = x.name,
                                          DepartmentID = x.id
                                      })
                              .ToArray();
```

Comment: I breakpoint them and it fails to initialize any variable. I am using subsonic and wondering if this is a fail on their part. It was working in linqpad with linq to sql

Comment: Forgot to mention this: When I did anonymous types it worked fine.

Comment: @Heinz: Yup - that's why I've used an anonymous type in my answer, so that it only fetches the information required... then converts it into your own object via LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Yeah, looks like your idea worked great! Thanks for the help, this has been killin' me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.
Maybe values are changing in ServiceDepartment or some where else.
if you didn't figure it out please post ServiceDepartment code.